# do while infinite loop stop on keyboard input - C

Tags: c, input, nonblocking

there is any way to run an infinite cycle that stops only on user input from keyboard
without asking every cycle to continue? in a C program
(I'm developing a C chat that read the entries with a `for(;;)` loop and I need to stop it only when the user want to type and send a message) hi all!

Comment: Looking for the `break` statement?

Comment: No, I think he's looking for a way to perform a non-blocking read from stdin

Comment: no I need one without give confirm every time EDIT: exactly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't specify the OS so I will assume some POSIX compliant OS.

You can use [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select). This can be used to block on a set of file descriptors (in your case, stdin) with a finite timeout or indefinite blocking.

My guess is, since this is a chat program, you would also want to do this on some other file descriptor, like your chat tcp socket. So you can test for input on both with *one* call.

In case of windows console, you should be able to use GetStdHandle and WaitForSingleObject/WaitForMultipleObjects if select does not work for you.

Comment: Windows has a POSIX compatibility layer and supports select().

Comment: @frx08: If it is windows, is it console? windows gui? you should specify that too.

Comment: In case of windows console, you should be able to use GetStdHandle and WaitForSingleObject.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways of doing this in Windows. Assuming you're using VC++, the easiest way is probably to use `_kbhit()`. If you want to use the Win32 API directly instead, you could call `GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents()` and see whether the return is non-zero.

You could also do an overlapped read, and each time through the loop call `WaitForSingleObject` with a timeout value of 0. The zero wait means it'll return immediately whether there's input or not. The return value will tell you whether you have any data: WAIT_TIMEOUT means no data has been read yet, and WAIT_OBJECT0 means you have some data waiting to be processed.

Comment: How to reset stdin handle from signaled state after using kbhit()/getch() in a loop to read keys from buffer?

Comment: @techtonik: If you're going to use the handle, you probably want to use the console functions throughout.